# Separable morphism induces surjectivity on tangent spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X, Y \in Sm/k$ are irreducible schemes where $Sm/k$ is the category of finite type smooth schemes over $k$. A dominant morphism $\phi:X \to Y$ is called separable if the induced field extension $k(X)/k(Y)$ is separably generated. 
Suppose $\phi: X \to Y$ is a dominant morphism. Then $\phi$ is separable if and only if there is some $x \in X$ such that the induced map on tangent spaces $d\phi_x : T_x X \to T_{f(x)}Y$ is surjective. The converse part I am doing by locally factoring $\phi$ as an etale map followed by a projection map. However I can't do the forward implication. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are finite type smooth schemes here.

Comment: If $\phi$ is separable, then you can check that it is smooth at the generic point of $X$. Then it is smooth at some closed point $x \in X$ and this $x$ should do the trick?